# String is ambiguous

Tags: c++, oop

Develop a simple payroll application for a company; there are three kinds of employees in the system:

- salaried employee,
- hourly employee,
- and commissioned employee.

Details of these employees is given below:

- Salaried Employees: name, tax rate, salary, set name, set name, get name, calculate salary, constructor, destructor
- Hourly Employees: name, tax rate, hours, hourly rate, get name, calculate salary, constructor, destructor
- Commissioned Employee: name, tax rate, sales, commission rate, get name, calculate salary, constructor, destructor

---

You have to perform following tasks:

1. Draw object-oriented model of the system using class hierarchy.
2. Implement appropriate constructor and destructor.
3. Write down appropriate setter/getter functions. Incorporate String class in the class hierarchy to deal with name of the employee.
4. Implement other member functions described above.
5. The system should take input as an array containing employee objects, calculates salary polymorphically (according to employee object), and generates report.
6. Demonstrate (5) using main function.

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<string.h>
    using namespace std;
    class string
    {
        char* s;
    public:
        string()
        {
    
        }
        string(const char* a)
        {
            if (a != NULL)
            {
                a = new char[strlen(a) + 1];
                strcpy(a, a);
            }
            else
                a = NULL;
        }
        void setstring(const char* a)
        {
            if (a != NULL)
            {
                delete[] a;
                a = NULL;
            }
            if (a != NULL)
            {
                a = new char[strlen(a) + 1];
                strcpy(s, a);
            }
        }
        const char* getString() const
        {
            return s;
        }
        string& operator = (const char* p)
        {
            delete[] s;
            if (p != NULL)
            {
                s = new char[strlen(p) + 1];
                strcpy(s, p);
            }
            else
                s = NULL;
            return *this;
        }
        friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const string& a)
        {
            os << a.s;
            return os;
        }
        ~string()
        {
            s = NULL;
            delete[] s;
        }
    };
    class Employee
    {
    private:
        string firstname;
        string lastname;
        string number;
    public:
        Employee()
        {
    
        }
        Employee(string first, string last, string n)
        {
            firstname = first;
            lastname = last;
            number = n;
        }
        void setfirstname(string first)
        {
            firstname = first;
        }
        string getfirstname()
        {
            return firstname;
        }
        void setlastname(string last)
        {
            lastname = last;
        }
        string getlastname()
        {
            return lastname;
        }
        void setnumber(string n)
        {
            number = n;
        }
        string getnumber()
        {
            return number;
        }
        virtual double earnings()=0;
    };
    class salariedemployee :public Employee
    {
    private:
        double weeklysalary;
    public:
        salariedemployee()
        {
    
        }
        salariedemployee(string first, string last, string n, float salary):Employee(first, last, n)
        {
            this->weeklysalary = salary;
             setweeklysalary(salary);
        }
        void setweeklysalary(double salary)
        {
            if (salary >= 0.0)
            {
                weeklysalary = salary;
            }
            else
                cout << "Weekly salary must be greater than or equal to 0.0"<<endl;
        }
        double getweeklysalary()
        {
            return weeklysalary;
        }
        double earnings()
        {
            return getweeklysalary();
        }
    };
    class hourlyemployee :public Employee
    {
    private:
        double wage;
        double hours;
    public:
        hourlyemployee()
        {
    
        }
        hourlyemployee(string first, string last, string n, double hourlywage, double hoursworked) :Employee(first, last, n)
        {
            setwage(hourlywage);
            sethours(hoursworked);
        }
        void setwage(double hourlywage)
        {
            if (hourlywage >= 0.0)
            {
                wage = hourlywage;
            }
            else
                cout << "Hourly wage must be greater than or equal to 0.0"<<endl;
        }
        double getwage()
        {
            return wage;
        }
        void sethours(double hoursworked)
        {
            if ((hoursworked >= 0.0) && (hoursworked <= 168.0))
            {
                hours = hoursworked;
            }
            else
                cout << "Hours must be greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than or equal to 168.0"<<endl;
        }
        double gethours()
        {
            return hours;
        }
        double earnings()
        {
            if (gethours() <= 40)   //no overtime
            {
                return getwage() * gethours();
            }
            else
                return 40 * getwage() + (gethours() - 40) * getwage() * 1.5;
        }
    };
    class commisionedemployee :public Employee
    {
    private:
        double grossSales;
        double commisionedrate;
    public:
        commisionedemployee()
        {
    
        }
        commisionedemployee(string first, string last, string n, double sales, double rates) :Employee(first, last, n)
        {
            setgrossSales(sales);
            setcommisionedrate(rates);
        }
        void setgrossSales(double sales)
        {
            if (sales >= 0.0)
            {
                grossSales = sales;
            }
            else
                cout << "Gross sales must be greater than or equal to 0.0"<<endl;
        }
        double getgrossSales()
        {
            return grossSales;
        }
        void setcommisionedrate(double rates)
        {
            if (rates > 0.0 && rates < 1.0)
            {
                commisionedrate = rates;
            }
            else
                cout << "Comminsioned rate must be greater than 0.0 and less than 1.0"<<endl;
        }
        double getcommisionedrate()
        {
            return commisionedrate;
        }
        double earnings()
        {
            return getcommisionedrate() * getgrossSales();
        }
    };
    int main()
    {
        /*salariedemployee SE("John", "Smith", "111", 80009);
        hourlyemployee HE("Kashif", "Gulzar", "5555", 4.2, 7.7);
        commisionedemployee CE("Sajid", "Bhatti", "444", 2.3, 3.3);
        cout << "Employee processed individually as:";
        cout <<"Salaried employee earned" << SE.earnings()<<endl;
        cout << "Hourly employee earned" << HE.earnings()<<endl;
        cout << "Commisioned employee earned" << CE.earnings() << endl;*/
    
        Employee* employees[3];
        employees[0] = new salariedemployee("John", "Smith", "111", 80009);
        employees[1] = new hourlyemployee("Kashif", "Gulzar", "5555", 4.2, 7.7);
        employees[2] = new commisionedemployee("Sajid", "Bhatti", "444", 2.3, 3.3);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            cout << "Name:" << employees[i]->getfirstname() << "  " << employees[i]->getlastname() << endl;
            cout << "Salary:" << employees[i]->earnings() << endl;
        }
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

It is giving me the error that string is ambiguous. how can i correct it?

Comment: `Employee::earnings` is empty; it doesn't return anything even though it promises that it will.  Note that no polymorphic lookup is done since `Employee::earnings` is not declared `virtual`.

Comment: You must be looking at the wrong code. It's clear that in `Employee::earnings` there is no return value. Make sure you look at the code the compiler error message is actually refering to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem:

```
class Employee{
// code...
        double earnings()
        {
            // returning nothing! problem   
        }
}
```

`earnings()` method is being **overridden** in all the derived classes. This is a strong hint that the base class method `Employee::earnings()` should be virtual. Moreover, it would be better even if you make it **Pure Virtual**. Why? Because you don't know anything about `Employee::earnings()`, you don't know what earnings it should return. When you don't have such information, you cannot accurately define this function or return a value from it. Hence, you make it pure virtual. A pure virtual function *must* be overridden by *every* derived class that derives from `Employee`.

How to make it pure virtual? Simple, change the above to:

```
   virtual double earnings() = 0;
```

Then in derived classes you can add the `override` keyword, to explicitly tell that you are overriding this function:

```
class salariedemployee :public Employee
{
//code...
    double earnings() override
    {
        //function definition code...
    }
}
```

Note that a class that has pure virtual function is an abstract class. Objects of such a class cannot be made:

```
Employee e; //error
Employee* e; //good
Employee* salaried = new salariedemployee("John", "Smith", "111", 80009); // good
```

Answer (score 2):

Your method head (the one inside class `Employee`)

```
double earnings()
```

promises that the body will return a value of type `double`.

Your method body

```
{}
```

does not do so, because it does not have a line with `return`, like e.g. `return 1.0;`.
That is what the compiler is telling you.

You do return something in the methods of the same name in the classes `salariedemployee` and `hourlyemployee`. That might be the reason why you did not look at the base class.

Maybe you intended to make the method in the base class purely abstract, like

```
double earnings()=0;
```

That would have the additional advantage that the compiler will tell you if ever you accidentally try to call it.

Since you declare

```
Employee* employees[3]; /* pointer to base class */
```

and call like

```
employees[i]->earnings()
```

you actually DO call the empty base class implementation.
You probably do not intend to and believe that the overrides in the derived classes should be called.
That however would require the method in the base class to be declared `virtual`.

So maybe your problem gets solved if you do

```
virtual double earnings()
{ /* any not purely abstract implementation ending in something like ... */
  return myDoubleVariable;
}
```

inside the base class.